# Jenkins Pipeline: git checks out wrong revision after triggered by Bitbucket Pull Request Builder

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I have a Jenkins pipeline which builds and tests pull requests on Bitbucket for my "engine" repository. I'm using the Bitbucket Pull Request Builder plugin, which checks out the PR branch, does a local merge against the target branch (using the "Merge Before Build" pipeline additional behavior), and then executes the pipeline in my Jenkinsfile.

The tests have some dependencies which are stored in other repositories. My Jenkinsfile checks these out into sub-directories (I've also tried checking them out into new directories in the parent, rather than as subdirectories).

```
node {
  dir('tools') { git url: 'ssh://git@bitbucket.org:<my_org>/tools.git', branch: 'master', credentialsId: 'my-cred-id' }
}
```

When this tools checkout step occurs, the git plugin tries to check out the HEAD commit of the "engine" repo in the "tools" directory:

#### First the main "engine" repo clones (triggered by the Bitbucket plugin, before the pipeline begins):

```
> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> git config remote.origin.url git@bitbucket.org:<my_org>/engine.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:<my_org>/engine.git
> git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials <creds>
> git fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:<my_org>/engine.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> git rev-parse 2ed413bbaf55^{commit} # timeout=10
> git branch -a -v --no-abbrev --contains 2ed413bbaf551428e5b6328829606155fdb8cd5e # timeout=10
Merging Revision 2ed413bbaf551428e5b6328829606155fdb8cd5e (origin/<branch>) to origin/dev, UserMergeOptions{mergeRemote='origin', mergeTarget='${targetBranch}', mergeStrategy='default', fastForwardMode='--ff'}
> git rev-parse origin/dev^{commit} # timeout=10
> git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> git checkout -f origin/dev
> git merge --ff 2ed413bbaf551428e5b6328829606155fdb8cd5e # timeout=10
> git rev-parse HEAD^{commit} # timeout=10
```

#### Then the tools repo clones (triggered by the `git` command in the pipeline):

```
> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> git config remote.origin.url git@bitbucket.org:<my_org>/tools.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:<my_org>/tools.git
> git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
> git fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:<my_org>/tools.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> git rev-parse 2ed413bbaf55^{commit} # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git rev-parse 2ed413bbaf55^{commit}" returned status code 128:
stdout: 2ed413bbaf55^{commit}

stderr: fatal: ambiguous argument '2ed413bbaf55^{commit}': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

The commit SHA pointed by the PR branch (`2ed413`) is the same commit SHA that git tries to check out when checking out the tools repo, which doesn't exist in that repository. Am I misconfiguring my pipeline? Or is this a bug?

Comment: We experience the same problem...

Comment: I am pretty sure now that this is a bug. I had to work around it by making a separate job and triggering it from my pipeline